# Swift setting UILabel height contraint to 0

Tags: xcode, swift

In my swift application I have a table view with table view cell that has three labels in it

[image]

I created a IBOutlet for each height contraint of the last label called "ID Info"

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelContraintHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!    
@IBOutlet weak var labelContraintHeightGreater: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

in my onViewLoad() i change the height constant for both:

```
labelContraintHeight.constant = 0
labelContraintHeightGreater.constant = 0
```

but the label still shows up.  I'm I missing something?  If I manually modify the constant values for both in the storyboard it does change size.  But I need to do it in the code since it may not always be hidden

Comment: Have you tried calling the label's `layoutIfNeeded()` method after making the constraint updates?

Comment: Those outlets dont have that method.  But I did try on the label that it belongs to:

Comment: Those outlets dont have that method.  But I did try on the label that it belongs to and event updateConstraints() but doesnt do anything